# How to generate button shapes with css that only one side will skew

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to design a button with a single side skewed with box-shadow - https://prnt.sc/10nawxl.
Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Check my answer please. I think it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could help you.
I found that we cannot use `clip-path` and `box-shadow` together.
So I used `drop-shadow` instead.

```css
button {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  clip-path: polygon(10px 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 17px 5px 5px 5px;
}
button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button-container {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 6px black);
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container"><button>Click me</button></div>
```

Comment: I think you can accept my answer if it is useful. ;)